# how can i make menu item (single) reset button?

Tags: kotlin, menuitem

I want to make reset button.
when I click reset button, `ischecked` will be set to **false** for *R.id.item1*, *R.id.item2*, and *R.id.item3*.

when I click button, I want to Group 'Mmenu' be checked to false

I tried `button.setOnClickListener(){item.isChecked = false}` in `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu)`
but didn't work...

And I tried same thing behind `when (item.itemId) {R.id.itemRotate ->`
but didn't work too...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        title = "제주도 풍경"

        button.setOnClickListener(){
            imageView1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            imageView1.rotation = Float.parseFloat("0")
            edtAngle.setText("0")
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        val mInflater = menuInflater
        mInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) : Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.itemRotate -> {
                imageView1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView1.rotation = Float.parseFloat(edtAngle.text.toString())
                return true
            }
            R.id.item1 -> {
                imageView1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.jeju2)
                item.isChecked = true

                return true
            }
            R.id.item2 -> {
                imageView1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.jeju14)
                item.isChecked = true
                return true
            }
            R.id.item3 -> {
                imageView1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.jeju6)
                item.isChecked = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

invalidateOptionsMenu()

this is solution to reset!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a HashMap :

```
var checked: HashMap<Int, Boolean> = HashMap()
```

Initialize to false

```
val ids = listOf(R.id.item1, R.id.item2, R.id.item3)

        ids.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
            checked[index] = false
        }
```

Then

```
when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.itemRotate -> {
                imageView1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView1.rotation = Float.parseFloat(edtAngle.text.toString())
                return true
            }
            R.id.item1 -> {
                imageView1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.jeju2)
                checked[item.itemId] = true

                return true
            }
            R.id.item2 -> {
                imageView1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.jeju14)
                checked[item.itemId] = true
                return true
            }
            R.id.item3 -> {
                imageView1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.jeju6)
                checked[item.itemId] = true
                return true
            }
        }
```

To reset:

```
fun reset() {
        ids.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
            checked[index] = false
        }
    }
```

To be called here:

```
button.setOnClickListener(){
        imageView1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        imageView1.rotation = Float.parseFloat("0")
        edtAngle.setText("0")
        reset()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! but I can't clear the problem... 'checked[index] = false' is not work checked[item.itemId] = true to... Sorry What should I do?